# Notification on answer updates

Tags: support, answers, notifications

I was wondering if it is posible to receive a notification when someone updates an answer to our question.

It has happened to me that someone answers my question without too much details and after a couple of days/hours that person edited the answer with a descriptive explanation and I don't notice it. Sometimes this explanation is really useful and provides technical details that should be updated.

It also happened with old answers that are like two months old, they were updated and we don't know about it.

Is it possible to know this?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the only way to do this, but you have the option of starring/favoriting your question, and then any updates to the question (or its answers) will show up in your profile page, and be highlighted with yellow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this feature. Thanks.

Comment: I think (apart from it's gamification side effects, that's actually what starring is for primarily)

Comment: I think question owner should receive the notification regardless of starring.